# Programmatically determine if a youtube video contains advertisements

Tags: video, youtube, rss

I'd like to programmatically determine if a youtube video contains advertisements. I searched quite a bit on the Internet and the YouTube API docs, and I couldn't find the answer.

Using the following `feed://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/{0}?v=2`, I'm able to check for the existence of the `'yt_state'` tag, which looks like this:

```
u'yt_state': {'reasoncode': u'limitedSyndication', 'name': u'restricted'}
```

This works most of the time for identifying videos that have advertisements. In fact, it the 'yt_state' tab is always present when an advertisement is present, but there are false positives. Sometimes the this tag is present for videos that show no ads, and I would like to remove the false positives.

Is there a better (official) way to check for advertisements?

Thanks!

Comment: What has this got to do with Python?

Comment: Python is my language of choice for solving this problem.